# What is the output dimension in the googlenet after the concat layer?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, concatenation

When looking throught the prototxt of the googlenet one finds that the inception layers have a concat layer at the end which takes several bottom inputs.

e.g:

```
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/output"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "inception_3a/1x1"
  bottom: "inception_3a/3x3"
  bottom: "inception_3a/5x5"
  bottom: "inception_3a/pool_proj"
  top: "inception_3a/output"
}
```

As it can be seen, there is one 1x1 conv-layer, one 3x3 conv-layer , one 5x5 conv-layer and finally a pooling layer. These layers are described as following:

```
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/1x1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2/3x3_s2"
  top: "inception_3a/1x1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.03
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/relu_1x1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "inception_3a/1x1"
  top: "inception_3a/1x1"
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/3x3_reduce"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2/3x3_s2"
  top: "inception_3a/3x3_reduce"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.09
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/relu_3x3_reduce"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "inception_3a/3x3_reduce"
  top: "inception_3a/3x3_reduce"
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/3x3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "inception_3a/3x3_reduce"
  top: "inception_3a/3x3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.03
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/relu_3x3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "inception_3a/3x3"
  top: "inception_3a/3x3"
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/5x5_reduce"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2/3x3_s2"
  top: "inception_3a/5x5_reduce"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.2
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/relu_5x5_reduce"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "inception_3a/5x5_reduce"
  top: "inception_3a/5x5_reduce"
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/5x5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "inception_3a/5x5_reduce"
  top: "inception_3a/5x5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.03
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/relu_5x5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "inception_3a/5x5"
  top: "inception_3a/5x5"
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/pool"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "pool2/3x3_s2"
  top: "inception_3a/pool"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "inception_3a/pool_proj"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "inception_3a/pool"
  top: "inception_3a/pool_proj"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      std: 0.1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

It can be seen that these have different numbers of output and also different filter size, anyhow the documentation on the concat layer is the following:

> input:
>
> `n_i * c_i * h * w for each input blob i from 1 to K.`
>
> Output:
>
> if axis = 0: `(n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_K) * c_1 * h * w`, and all input c_i
>   should be the same.
>
> if axis = 1: `n_1 * (c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_K) * h * w`, and all input n_i should be the same.

Firstly, I am not sure what the default is and secondly I am not sure which Dimensions will have the output Volume, since width and height should stay the same but all thre conv layer produce different outputs. Any pointers would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for 'Concat' axis is 1, thus concatenating through channel dimension. In order to do this, all the layers that are concatenated, should have the same height and width. Looking to the log, the dimensions are (assuming batch size 32):

inception_3a/1x1 -> [32, 64, 28, 28]
inception_3a/3x3 -> [32, 128, 28, 28]
inception_3a/5x5 -> [32, 32, 28, 28]
inception_3a/pool_proj -> [32, 32, 28, 28]

Thus the final output will have dimension:
inception_3a/output -> [32 (64+128+32+32) 28, 28] -> [32, 256, 28, 28]

As expected from the Caffe log:

```
Creating Layer inception_3a/output
inception_3a/output <- inception_3a/1x1
inception_3a/output <- inception_3a/3x3
inception_3a/output <- inception_3a/5x5
inception_3a/output <- inception_3a/pool_proj
inception_3a/output -> inception_3a/output
Setting up inception_3a/output
Top shape: 32 256 28 28 (6422528)
```

Comment: if the axis would be 2, or 3 and so in it would be on the the following dimensions ?

Comment: Yes, but notice that in this case it will not work since all the layers have a different number of channels. In practice, all input axes must have the same dimensions except for the concat axis, as reported in the code: [concat_layer.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cpp)